# HttpListenerException whenever trying to start an HttpListener in C#

Tags: c#, http, exception, proxy, httplistener

Ttoday I started looking more into `HttpListener` and what it is, so I apologize if my knowledge isn't very extensive when it comes to this or how it works. But when trying to use the `Start()` method to start my `HttpListener` I get this exception:

`Can't start the agent to listen transactionSystem.Net.HttpListenerException (32): The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`

And this exception also has something to do with the prefix itself too.

Here is the code I'm using, it's the third time I've had to redo it but I still get the same exception.

```
static void ListenTraces()
        {
            try
            {
                var httpListener = new HttpListener();

                httpListener.Prefixes.Add("https://discord.com/");
                try
                {
                    httpListener.Start(); //this line is where the exception happens
                }
                catch (HttpListenerException hlex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Can't start the agent to listen transaction" + hlex);
                    return;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Now ready to receive traces...");
                while (true)
                {
                    var context = httpListener.GetContext(); 

                    Console.WriteLine(context.Response);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

All help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

There might be something else listening on that port already (do you have any other dev server running?)

Try to configure the agent port to be something else, by changing a registry value.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MsDepSvc\Parameters\ListenUrl
```

By default this value should be `http://+:80/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE/`. You can change the 80 to be e.g. 81. Then restart your service.